# Does Xcode or gcc have a macro for developer name?

Tags: xcode, gcc

Xcode obviously knows my name because it puts it at the top of each new file I create (created by Quentin Liedtke) and also has my first name in the xcuserdata folder (Quentin.xcuserdatad).

I'd like to be able to harness this in my code. Is there a preprocessor macro or configuration function or some other way that I can get this string in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question:

in Build Settings -> Preprocess Macros add:

```
DEVELOPER_NAME=@\""$USER"\"
```

Then it can be used in code thusly:

```
NSLog("%@", DEVELOPER_NAME);
```